# How to prove the limit of given two variables function does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Please help me to prove that the limit of the following function does not exist:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{\sin(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}}$

My slolution:

1. Choose functions
   g1(x,y) and g2(x,y), the same limit = 0 at (x,y)= (0,0)
2. Calculate and compare limit(g1(x,y), x,y) with limit(g2(x,y), x,y).

It is not difficult to find that g1(x,y) and g2(x,y) satisfy the requirement 1.

The problem is that for all the functions gi(x,y) that I have chosen, calculating the limit of the gi(x,y) functions is difficult because the indefinite form of the limits cannot be eliminated. Please help me find the appropriate g1(x,y) and g2(x,y) functions.
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what happens if you set $x$ constant and move towards 0 on the $y$ axis? How about vice-versa?

Comment: Set $x=0$ and take $\lim_{y \to 0}$ to get $-1$, then set $y=0$ and take $\lim_{x\to 0}$ to get $+1$.

Comment: With your suggestion, the problem is solved. Thanks very much!